# How to format a table in JOptionpane?

Tags: java, joptionpane

So, I have a program which searches through a file to find desired information that the user wants, and I am trying to output it in a nice table in JOptionPane to make it easier to read, but I keep getting something like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/tanOzDh.png]

I would like the lines to line up accordingly and be formatted properly, here is the code for that particular message:

```
 String message=String.format("%-10s|%7s|%14s|%13s|%22s", element,symbol,atomicNumber,atomicMass,valence);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name      |Symbol |Atomic Number |Atomic Mass  |# of Valence Electrons  \n _________________________________________________________________ \n " + message);
```

Can't seem to figure out what i'm doing wrong here, I used the exact same format code in a different assignment in which it only utilized the terminal and it worked fine, but now that I'm trying to use it in JOptionPane it's not formatting properly.

Any ideas on how to fix this or make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try JTable instead:

```
Object[][] rows = {
    {element,symbol,atomicNumber,atomicMass,valence}
};
Object[] cols = {
    "Name","Symbol","Atomic Number","Atomic Mass", "# of Valence Electrons"
};
JTable table = new JTable(rows, cols);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));
```

Comment: 1+, but you need to add the table to a JScrollPane (and then display the scrollpane in the option pane) in order for the headers to display.

Comment: 1- (I removed the upvote), The suggestion is not about the scrollbars, it is about displaying the header values. If you don't add the table to the scrollpane you will only see the data. The requirement is to display the header and data. So the scrollpane is NOT optional to meet that requirement.

Comment: Thank you! I used the JTable and addded it to the JScrollPane and it worked exactly how I wanted it to.

Comment: what will that print out??

Comment: @SakshamGoyal, its gonna give a popup containing table with the given rows and columns

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the terminal and your Swing dialog is that the former using a fixed width font, while the latter uses a variable width font. For example: if you look at the picture you posted, you can see that the 'i' is far less wide than the 'm'. That means that a String 15 characters long does not necessarily take up the same space as another String of the same length.

The correct solution to format something like this in Swing is to use either a [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) or a [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). If you are happy to use a third party library I recommend looking at [DesignGridLayout](https://designgridlayout.java.net/).

You could also set the font explicitly, but that would still require you to change your code and it would look a bit archaic in the context of a Swing application.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas on how to fix this or make it work?

In the context of a brute force solution for the JOptionPane you should be able to specify an Array of Objects to be used by the option pane. So the code would be something like:

```
JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[3];
JLabel heading = new JLabel(...);
heading.setFont( ("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12) );
labels[0] = heading;
JLabel line = new JLabel(...);
...
JLabel data = new JLabel(...);
...
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, labels);
```

This is not a very good solution, but I just wanted to demonstrate the flexibility of JOptionPane to display multiple components organized vertically.

Another option might be to play with the UIManager and change the default font for the option pane. The code would be something like:

```
Font original = UIManager.getFont("Label.font");
UIManager.put("Label.font", new Font(...)); // specify your monospaced font here
JOptionPane.showMessage(...);
UIManager.put("Label.font", original); // restore default font
```

I'm not sure if this font applies to all the components on the option pane or just the buttons or just the display components.

The JTable would be the better approach for my money.